# Filtering SAS datasets created with PROC IMPORT with dmbs=xlsx

Tags: excel, sas, filtering, xlsx

My client uses **SAS 9.3** running on an **AIX (IBM Unix) server**. The client interface is **SAS Enterprise Guide 5.1**.

I ran into this really puzzling problem: when using `PROC IMPORT` in combination with `dbms=xlsx`, it seems impossible to filter rows based on the value of a character variable (at least, when we look for an exact match).

With an **.xls** file, the following import works perfectly well; the expected subset of rows is written to `myTable`:

```
proc import out = myTable(where=(myString EQ "ABC"))
  datafile ="myfile.xls"
  dbms = xls replace;
run;
```

However, using the *same data* but this time in an **.xlsx** file, an **empty dataset** is created (having the right number of variables and adequate column types).

```
proc import out = myTable(where=(myString EQ "ABC"))
  datafile ="myfile.xlsx"
  dbms = xlsx replace;
run;
```

Moreover, if we **exclude the `where`** from the `PROC IMPORT`, the data is *seemingly* imported correctly. However, filtering is **still** not possible. For instance, this will create an **empty dataset**:

```
data myFilteredTable;
  set myTable;
  where myString EQ "ABC";
run;
```

The following will work, but is obviously not satisfactory:

```
data myFilteredTable;
  set myTable;
  where myString LIKE "ABC%";
run;
```

Also note that:

- Using `compress` or other string functions does not help
- Filtering using numerical columns works fine for both **xls** and **xlsx** files.
- My preferred method to read spreadsheets is to use excel libnames, but this is technically not possible at this time.

I wonder if this is a known issue, I couldn't find anything about it so far. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you have an extra character at the end of `myString`.  Have you checked to verify that isn't the case?  (`put myString $HEX.;` would be a good start)

Comment: I checked and no extra characters are present.

Comment: I would check again, then, and inspect carefully that hex dump.  I could see an XLSX import engine bug causing the WHERE to not work properly in the dataset options, but I couldn't see it working that way in the SAS data step itself.  Something's fishy there.  Maybe it's Unicode-related or something like that (more generally, codepage-related), but something must be causing a character to be showing up after ABC, if `where mystring eq "ABC"` fails all rows and `where mystring like "ABC%"` doesn't.

Comment: ok I see what's happening. With `dbms=xls`, blanks (difference between number of characters and the variable length) are filled with hex `20`s (spaces), as they should. With `dbms=xlsx`, it's rather `00`s (NULs). Not sure yet how we'll handle this, but at least we're a step closer... Thanks for your help Joe.

Comment: That makes sense - and sounds like a bug in the XLSX import routine.  It may be fixed in a hotfix or in 9.4; I would file a ticket with SAS tech support.

Comment: Definitely, I'll pass the info to the sys admins. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your strings have extra values on the end not being picked up by `compress`. Try using the `countc` function on `MyString` to see if any extra characters exist on the end. You can then figure out what characters to remove with `compress` once they're determined.